# deletes everything from the database,the getRef() method does not work because i cant put my dialog inside the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

RETRIEVADATA CLASS

package com.dikolobe.salesagent;

public class RetrieveData extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,OnNoteClickListener{

private static final String TAG = "";

```
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;

//FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;

FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;

DatabaseReference mRef;

FirebaseStorage mStorage;

ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter;

List<Product> productList=new ArrayList<>();

RecyclerView recyclerView;

TextView phone_num;

ViewHolder viewHolder;

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

ImageView img;

OnNoteClickListener onNoteClickListener;

Context context;

private List<Product> listItems= new ArrayList<>();

private List<Product> listItemsFull;

public ArrayList<Product> filterList = new ArrayList<>();

private int progressStatus = 0;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

String imageUrl = null;

SearchView searchView;

//ImageView delete;

String productId;

String image;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrieve_data);

   // delete =findViewById(R.id.delete);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)

                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

            Log.d("permission", "permission denied to SEND_SMS - requesting it");

            String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS};

            requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

        }

    }

    searchView=findViewById(R.id.search);

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Product> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Product>()

            .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()

                    .child("Items"),Product.class)

            .build();

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    mRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("Items");

    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    productList = new ArrayList<Product>();

    itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(RetrieveData.this, productList,this,options);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override

        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            Product product = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);

            productList.add(product);

            itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override

        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override

        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override

        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override

        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });

}

@Override

protected void onStart(){

    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Product> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Product>()

            .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()

                    .getReference().child("Items"), Product.class)

                            .build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override

        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull com.dikolobe.salesagent.ViewHolder holder, final int
```

position, @NonNull Product product) {

```
        }

        @NonNull

        @Override

        public com.dikolobe.salesagent.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int
```

viewType) {

```
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())

                    .inflate(R.layout.design_row_for_recyclerview, parent, false);

            return new com.dikolobe.salesagent.ViewHolder(view,onNoteClickListener);

        }

        public void deleteProduct(int position) {

            try{

                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Items")

                        .child(getRef(position).getKey())

                        .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                    @Override

                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        Toast.makeText(context,"Deleted succesfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                });

            }

            catch (Exception e){

                Log.e("error", e.getMessage());

            }

        }


    };

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


}
```

@Override

protected void onStop() {

```
super.onStop();
```

firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();

}

```
@Override
```

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

```
MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();

menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.search);

SearchView searchView=(SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

        search_product(query);

      // itemsAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);

        return false;

    }



    @Override

      public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

          search_product(newText);

         //itemsAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());

          return false;

      }

  });

  return true;
```

}

@Override

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

```
  if (item.getItemId() == R.id.add_product) {



      startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));



      Toast.makeText(this, "post a product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.tutorial) {

      // startActivity(new Intent(this, AddRider.class));



      //  Toast.makeText(this,"Add a rider to an Event",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



  } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.logOut) {

      startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));



      Toast.makeText(this, "bye", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



  }

  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

}

ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback=new

ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {

```
  @Override


  public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, Re
```

cyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

```
      return false;

    }



    @Override

    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {



        removeItem((long) viewHolder.itemView.getTag());

        productList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

        itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    }



    private void removeItem(long id) {

    }

};





    private boolean updateItem(String seller, String description, String price,String location,String
```

phone,String productId,String image,String posted_date) {

```
        //getting the specified product reference

        DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Items").child(productId);



        //updating product

        Product product = new Product(productId, seller,
```

description,price,phone,location,image,posted_date);

```
        dR.setValue(product);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Product Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;

    }





@Override

public void onNoteClick(final int position) {



    CharSequence[] items = {"Update", "Delete"};

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RetrieveData.this);

    dialog.setTitle("Choose Action");


            dialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            if(i == 0){



                Intent update_activty = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Update_Product.class);

                startActivity(update_activty);



            }

            if (i==1){

                Product product=productList.get(position);

                productId =product.getProductId();

                image =product.getImage();



                    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogdelete = new
```

AlertDialog.Builder(RetrieveData.this);

```
                    dialogdelete.setTitle("Warning");

                    dialogdelete.setMessage("Are You Sure You Want to Delete?");


                    dialogdelete.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                        @Override

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {



                            Query mQuery = mRef.orderByChild("productId").equalTo(productId);


                            mQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                                @Override

                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                    for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                                        ds.getRef().removeValue();

                                    }
```

Toast.makeText(RetrieveData.this,"deleted..!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

```
                                }



                                @Override

                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
```

Toast.makeText(RetrieveData.this,databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

```
                                }

                            });



                           Query mPictureReference =
```

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Items").orderByChild("image").equalTo(image);

```
                            mPictureReference.getRef().removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new
```

OnSuccessListener() {
@Override

```
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                    Toast.makeText(RetrieveData.this,"Image
```

deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

```
                                }

                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

                                @Override

                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                    Toast.makeText(RetrieveData.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }

                            });

                        }

                    });

                    dialogdelete.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            dialogInterface.dismiss();

                        }

                    });

                    dialogdelete.show();



            }



        }



    });

    dialog.show();



    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"cliked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



}



@Override

public void onClick(View v) {



}



public static String getTimeDate(long timestamp){

    try{

        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();

        Date netDate = (new Date(timestamp));

        return dateFormat.format(netDate);

    } catch(Exception e) {

        return "date";

    }

}
```

}

ADAPTER CLASS

package com.dikolobe.salesagent;

public class ItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements Filterable {

```
public ArrayList<Product> filterList = new ArrayList<>();

private int progressStatus = 0;


private Handler handler = new Handler();

private OnNoteClickListener onNoteClickListener;

Context context;

private List<Product> listItems;

private List<Product> listItemsFull;

private Product product;

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Product> options;



String imageUrl = null;



public ItemsAdapter(Context context, List<Product> listItems,OnNoteClickListener
```

onNoteClickListener,FirebaseRecyclerOptions options) {

```
    this.context = context;


    this.listItems = listItems;

    listItemsFull = new ArrayList<>(listItems);

    this.onNoteClickListener = onNoteClickListener;

    this.options=options;

}



public ItemsAdapter(FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Product> options) {

}





@NonNull


@Override

public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


    View v =
```

LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.design_row_for_recyclerview,parent,false);

```
    return new ViewHolder(v,onNoteClickListener);

}

@Override

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {



    product = listItems.get(position);

    holder.seller.setText(listItems.get(position).getSeller());

    holder.desc.setText(listItems.get(position).getDescription());

    holder.price.setText(listItems.get(position).getPrice());

    holder.location.setText(listItems.get(position).getLocation());

    holder.phone.setText(listItems.get(position).getPhone());

    holder.time.setText((CharSequence) listItems.get(position).getPosted_date());



    holder.progress_Bar = new ProgressBar(context);

    

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {


            while (progressStatus < 100) {

                progressStatus += 1;

                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        holder.progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);

                        holder.textView.setText(progressStatus+"/"+holder.progressBar.getMax());

                    }

                });

                try {

                    Thread.sleep(200);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

        }

    }).start();





    imageUrl = product.getImage();

    Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {

        @Override

        public void onSuccess() {

            holder.image_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }



        @Override

        public void onError(Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });

    holder.phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {



            int id=v.getId();

            if (id==R.id.phoneTv){



                String phoneNumber = product.getPhone();

                String message = "I am interested";

                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);

                Toast.makeText(context,"Interest message sent successfully",
```

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

```
            }





        }

    });

    holder.call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            int id=v.getId();

            if(id==R.id.call){



                String phoneNumber = product.getPhone();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNumber));

                context.startActivity(intent);

            }

        }

    });    }


@Override

public int getItemCount() {

    return listItems.size();

}



@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    return filterProducts;
}

private Filter filterProducts = new Filter() {

    @Override

    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        ///*to delete*/String search_text = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        List<Product> productFiltrate = new ArrayList<>();

        if (constraint.length()==0 ){

            productFiltrate.addAll(listItemsFull);

        }else

        {

            String pattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (Product product:listItemsFull){

                if(product.getSeller().toLowerCase().contains(pattern)){

                    productFiltrate.add(product);

                }

            }

        }

        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

        filterResults.values = productFiltrate;

        return filterResults;

    }



    @Override

    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        filterList.clear();

        filterList.addAll((List) results.values);

        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

};
```

}

INSERT DATA/MAIN_ACTIVITY

package com.dikolobe.salesagent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
```

ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter;

```
FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;

DatabaseReference mRef;

FirebaseStorage mStorage;

EditText seller_name,desc,price,location,phone;

Button btnInsert,list;

ImageButton imageButton,take_Photo;

ProgressBar progressBar;

private ProgressDialog mProgress;

Uri imageUri = null;

final int REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE=999;

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private int progressStatus = 0;

private TextView textView;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

ViewHolder holder;

FrameLayout image_layout;


@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    seller_name = findViewById(R.id.seller_nameEt);

    desc = findViewById(R.id.descEt);

    price = findViewById(R.id.priceEt);

    location = findViewById(R.id.locationEt);

    phone = findViewById(R.id.phoneEt);

    btnInsert = findViewById(R.id.save);

    //list = findViewById(R.id.list);

    imageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    image_layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_image);

    take_Photo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.take_pic);

    take_Photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            int id = v.getId();

            if (id==R.id.take_pic){

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            }

        }

    });



    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    mRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("Items");

    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();



    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,

                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE);

        }

    });

    progressBar = new ProgressBar(MainActivity.this);

    image_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {



            image_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    while (progressStatus < 100) {

                        progressStatus += 1;

                        // Update the progress bar and display the

                        //current value in the text view

                        handler.post(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {

                                progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);

                                textView.setText(progressStatus+"/"+progressBar.getMax());

                            }

                        });

                        try {

                            // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.

                            Thread.sleep(200);

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }
                }

            }).start();



            final String seller = seller_name.getText().toString().trim();

            final String fn = desc.getText().toString().trim();

            final String ln = price.getText().toString().trim();

            final String place = location.getText().toString().trim();

            final String phon = phone.getText().toString().trim();

            final String id = mRef.push().getKey();



            if (!(seller.isEmpty() && fn.isEmpty() && ln.isEmpty() && place.isEmpty() &&
```

phon.isEmpty() && imageUri!=null)){

```
                StorageReference filepath =
```

mStorage.getReference().child("images").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());

```
                filepath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new
```

OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

```
                    @Override

                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                        image_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        Task<Uri> downloadUrl =
```

taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

```
                            @Override

                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {

                                String t=task.getResult().toString();

                                final DatabaseReference newPost=mRef.push();

                                newPost.child("seller").setValue(seller);


                                newPost.child("description").setValue(fn);

                                newPost.child("price").setValue(ln);

                                newPost.child("location").setValue(place);

                                newPost.child("phone").setValue(phon);

                                newPost.child("productId").setValue(id);

                                newPost.child("image").setValue(task.getResult().toString());



                                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

                                Date date = new Date();

                                String strDate = dateFormat.format(date).toString();

                                newPost.child("posted_date").setValue(strDate);

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"successfully uploaded",
```

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

```
                                seller_name.setText("");

                                desc.setText("");

                                price.setText("");

                                location.setText("");

                                phone.setText("");

                                imageButton.setImageURI(null);

                                goToRetrieveDataClass();

                            }



                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

                            @Override

                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed to
```

upload..!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

```
                            }

                        });


                    }

                });

            }else Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please write all your
```

details..!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

```
        }



    });



    if (!hasCamera())

        take_Photo.setEnabled(false);

}



@Override

protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();

   // firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

}

@Override

protected void onStop() {

    super.onStop();

   // firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();

}

private Boolean hasCamera() {

    return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);

}



public void launchCamera(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

}



@Override

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[]
```

grantResults) {

```
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE) {

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            gallery.setType("image/*");

            startActivityForResult(gallery, REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE);

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "no permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        return;

    }

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);



}

@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


        imageUri = data.getData();

        CropImage.activity(imageUri).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)

                .setAspectRatio(1,1).start(this);


        imageButton.setImageURI(imageUri);


    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        }

        else if(resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE){

            Exception error = result.getError();



        }

    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data);

}
```

}

Comment: I want to delete only specified record when I click on the item

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **1300** lines of code for this issue. That's way too much for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.